# Static Div in CSS Grid Transition to Fill Screen

Tags: css, animation, position, css-transitions, css-grid

I've made a number of blocks in a CSS grid layout as follows:

```js
$('.box').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(10, [row] 1fr) / repeat(14, [col] 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
   height: calc(100vh - 40px);
   width: calc(100vw - 40px);
   margin:20px;
}

.box{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:1;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  background-color:#ebebeb;
  
}

.box.active{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  z-index:50;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-column: col 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 1 / span 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);
}

.item-2 {
  grid-column: col 13 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 1 / span 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 8 / span 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #d38312, #a83279);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-column: col 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 5 / span 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #b3ffab, #12fff7);
}

.item-5 {
  grid-column: col 13 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 9 / span 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #485563, #29323c);
}

.item-6 {
  grid-column: col 4 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 2 / span 2;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fe8c00, #f83600);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="box item-1">1</div>
<div class="box item-2">2</div>
<div class="box item-3">3</div>
<div class="box item-4">4</div>
<div class="box item-5">5</div>
<div class="box item-6">6</div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks one of the coloured boxes I want it to expand and slide across the screen to fill 100% of the height and width of the screen.

Currently, when clicked each box expands to 100vh and 100vw, but because it is static positioned on a CSS grid, I can't move it to cover the screen.

If I use position:absolute on .box.active the transition isn't smooth, and looks very ugly. If I use position:absolute on .box, then the .box divs are no longer positioned in the grid...

Is there an elegant solution so that the boxes remain in the grid, but when clicked expand and move to fill the whole screen? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Take the `height: 100vh;` and `width: 100vw;` out and add in `grid-area: 1 / 1 / -1 / -1;` to `box.active`

Comment: Thanks for this, useful technique - but is there a way to implement this so that there is a smooth transition and the box slides across the screen as it gets larger, rather than just jumping to the larger size?

Comment: After doing some research, I don't think grid properties are animateable in most browsers yet... https://codepen.io/matuzo/post/animating-css-grid-layout-properties. There may be a way to do this with javascript. I'll see if I can whip something up. I tried all variations of grid on the container div and nothing seemed to work via CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little hacky (and I got rid of that pesky jQuery :P) but give it a shot ...

```js
function bigger() {
  if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
    this.classList.remove('active')
  } else {
    this.classList.add('active');
  }
}
  
const el = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const elArray = [...el];

elArray.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', bigger);
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template: repeat(10, [row] 1fr) / repeat(14, [col] 1fr);
   grid-gap: 20px;
   height: calc(100vh - 40px);
   width: calc(100vw - 40px);
   margin:20px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
 .box {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index:1;
   font-size: 10px;
   line-height: 1;
   color: white;
   transition: 1s;
   background-color:#ebebeb;
}
 .box.active {
   transform: scale3d(20, 20, 1);
   transform-origin: center;
   z-index:50;
}
 .item-1 {
   grid-column: col 1 / span 2;
   grid-row: row 1 / span 2;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);
}
 .item-2 {
   grid-column: col 13 / span 2;
   grid-row: row 1 / span 2;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);
   opacity: 0.8;
}
 .item-3 {
   grid-column: col 3 / span 2;
   grid-row: row 8 / span 2;
   background: linear-gradient(to top, #d38312, #a83279);
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 0.8;
}
 .item-4 {
   grid-column: col 1 / span 2;
   grid-row: row 5 / span 2;
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #b3ffab, #12fff7);
}
 .item-5 {
   grid-column: col 13 / span 2;
   grid-row: row 9 / span 2;
   background: linear-gradient(to top, #485563, #29323c);
}
 .item-6 {
   grid-column: col 4 / span 2;
   grid-row: row 2 / span 2;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #fe8c00, #f83600);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="box item-1">1</div>
  <div class="box item-2">2</div>
  <div class="box item-3">3</div>
  <div class="box item-4">4</div>
  <div class="box item-5">5</div>
  <div class="box item-6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice simple solution, thanks. If I'm correct, another more complex but more precise way to do this could be to use jQuery.offset() and slide a new div from the coordinates of each item to the coordinates of each item.active. I'll try to put together an example when I have some more time in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.box.active{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index:50;
}
```

Comment: This is good - but I wanted a smooth transition where the box would slide from its current position to fill the screen - is that possible with this method?